# Integrate $\int_{0}^{\infty }\frac{1}{\sqrt{2x-1}}dx$

Tags: integration

Firstly, I want to ask if  I can solve it numerically and how treat with the infinity value.
If the numerical solution is impossible, how can I do by using the integration methods.
$$\int_{0}^{\infty }\frac{1}{\sqrt{2x-1}}dx$$

Comment: Well for start, your integral doesn't converge so you'll have a hard time finding a value..

Comment: As a real valued function, the integrand only exists for $x>1/2$.

Answer (score 0):

As for the Integral $$\int{1\over \sqrt{2x-1}} \ dx$$

You can re-write $${1\over \sqrt{2x-1}}=(2x-1)^{-1\over2}$$

So now we have $$\int{(2x-1)^{-1\over2}} \ dx$$ Now by substituting $u=(2x-1)^{-1\over2}$ we can easily integrate $u^{-1\over2}$

We add one to the power and multiply that by the coefficient out front. Then we differentiate the inside and multiply it out front also.

Which yeilds:$$\int{u^{-1\over2}}=2{1\over 2}u^{1\over 2}=u^{1\over 2}$$

So now since your integral is going from $0 \to \infty$ We evaluate it $$u^{1\over 2}\bigg|_0^\infty=(2x-1)^{1\over 2}\bigg|_0^\infty=(2(\infty)-1)^{1\over 2}-(2(0)-1)^{1\over 2}=\infty-i$$

Comment: I think I did everything right, but I'm not sure what to do if you get an imaginary answer.

Comment: You can't do that, since complex integrals are very different and are not evaluated that way (one reason is you have to specify the path on the complex plane). I doubt this is the intention, so the only way is to say this integral is undefined, since the domain is $x \ge 1/2$

Comment: @Dylan You could evaluate the integral of a complex valued function of a real variable, without resort to complex analysis, it's not a problem (in complex integration, it's the variable that is complex). This answer is wrong, for other reasons.